# I cannot launch Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I just updated the "nbclassic" package with pip, and now when I want to run Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
notebook 6.5.1 requires nbclassic==0.4.5, but you have nbclassic 0.4.6 which is incompatible.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Or do I have to downgrade the package to the needed version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need nbclassic to be 0.4.6 for another dependency you are best suited creating a venv, so you will be able to have both versions of it, else you can just downgrade the version